# Android In App Purchasing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing, in-app-billing

I've got a quiz app on the Android market right now selling for $1. I would like to offer a free version with limited questions, and include a menu offering the user to upgrade to the full version.

My question is simply what the best practice is here?

The possibilities I can conceive are:

1. Have a link in the free version that takes the user to the paid
   version's url on the android market, whereby they'd just download the full version directly.
2. Have condition statements in the free version that limit the
   number of questions available if VERSION == FREE, enable all
   questions upon purchase by setting VERSION = PAID.
3. Download the additional questions upon the purchase
   (would that require my own file server?)

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say there is a best practice between these 3 variants, you should just choose the more appropriate approach for you and your application. First variant is the simplest for you as a developer, second offers a better user experience, but you need to implement In-App Billing in your app. And the third approach is the most difficult cause you'll need a server to store your files on. I'd personally choose the first approach, since the second one has a pitfall - you need the locked questions to be inside your demo version's apk and it's just not secure. The much more secure approach is to not put them in your demo version - this is what the first approach gives you. However, it's your choice as a developer. Good luck!